# How do I convert the entire Intranet- Mediawiki site to Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mediawiki

I have installed Mediawiki on NAS and Wordpress on Ubuntu-sever.
I need to convert the entire mediawiki site to wordpress format and run on Ubuntu.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how well this works, but Wordpress has a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-automated-mediawiki-to-wp-migration/) to do this for you. Let us know how it went!

Running Wordpress on Ubuntu should be easy enough if you have a PHP enabled webserver with a MySQL database. You can follow the [installation instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) provided by Wordpress, they are excellent.

Comment: Did you try the Wordpress plugin I posted a link to (first paragraph)?